# Mosquitto-Dynamic Bridging

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto, bridging

I wanted to know if any of you have tried this  - https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/pull/535/files
Mosquitto is working fine but what payload to be sent with this topic? - $SYS/broker/bridge/new
I am unable to implement dynamic bridging, please help me out.

Comment: Edit the question to show what you have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message should be the same as the bridge configuration you would include in the `mosquitto.conf` file. You can see where the tool builds the message in the patch linked to the pull request [here](https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/pull/535/files#diff-c048b63259c5a4f8f42f9e65e3f79e10R233)

```
connection [name]
address [address]:[port]
topic [pattern] [direction] [qos] [local prefix] [remote prefix]
```

But by the look of things this functionality has not been merged into the release branch of mosquitto. The last comment on the linked [pull](https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/pull/653) request implies that it only works up to 1.5.4 and not on the latest 1.6.x code base.

Answer (score 0):

I did see comment by the author on [pull request 635](https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/pull/653).

Dynamic bridges was working with version 1.6.10 and he has initiated a request for latest release as well.

[GitHub repository](https://github.com/Tifaifai/mosquitto)